# Share a whatsapp contact over HTML

Tags: html, share, contacts, whatsapp

I would like to create an HTML link so that anyone could easily find me on whatsapp. There is URL Schema that whatsapp provides but there is no way I found on the documentation to share a contact. The only functionality the schema handles is that of sending a message and optionally include an user ID from the existing library.

How would you address this problem? Is there any way to create a contact in the phonebook using HTML? That will also work.

The closest thing I have found is the html "tel" tag, but that may launch other applications other than the contact list to add a new contact.

Comment: There is a desktop version of whatsapp...perhaps unofficial but there is one

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this issue. It is not perfect, but its the best approach.

Currently the whatsapp protocol does have any features for creating new contacts, but it does have one to send a message to one of your existing contacts/chats. So what I did is to share a message with my contacts details.

`whatsapp://send?text=join%20me%20on%20TELEPHONE_NUMBER_HERE%20%3A)`

This will open the whatsapp app an the user will see:

`join me on TELEPHONE_NUMBER :)`

It is not a perfect solution but is something if you want to add a whatsapp link in your site.

Hope it helps.